How to get the The Knight outfit
With the Dead Cells x Hollow Knight crossover (more of a reference, really), you can unlock the Pure Nail and the The Knight outfit in Dead Cells.
I’ve unlocked the Pure Nail already, but how do you get the The Knight outfit?

The crossover outfit from Hollow Knight is called the Vessel's Outfit. The Knight's Outfit refers to the outfit from Soul Knight.
According to the Dead Cells wiki's outfit list, the Vessel's Outfit from Hollow Knight is unlocked by using the Pure Nail to bounce 8 times without touching the ground. This is most easily done while fighting an enemy with high HP such as a boss.
